# how to crop some portion of scaled, rotated image-view

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, crop, image-rotation, image-scaling

I am unable to crop he image from image view, which is scaled and rotated before cropping. used existing cropping methods.but its applicable only for image-view which is fixed.Hope code will helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally succeeded cropping rotated scaled image.

1) Need to crop the entire scaled or rotated image.

2)crop the rect from cropped Image. you will get final scaled or rotated cropped image.

Im posting sample code , it may helpful for others.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100,100 ,200, 200);//Rect we need from scaled or rotated image.
CGImageRef cropped = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(viewImage.CGImage, rect);
UIImage *img =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped]; 
CGImageRelease(cropped);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your image rotated or the view? In my case imageview is rotated and scaled, not the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try This(if you need to crop the corners):

```
UIImageView *imageSubview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 5.0f,80.0f, 60.0f)];

[imageSubview setImage:actualImage]; 
[imageSubview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[imageSubview.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
[imageSubview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell addSubview:imageSubview];
```

Just increase the radius and you will make it circle, or walk on this path you'll get your actual solution.:)

Comment: Thanks for Update. I need middle of the image,or anywhere in image view like image picker image editing property!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0));
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([myImage CGImage], cropRect);

UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cropRect];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage]]; 

CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
```

its for cropping particular height and width

Comment: Thanks for update.
But already worked with logic, workes with fixed image. Once scaled or rotating image, its not working, always returns same image.




 CGRect rect = CGRectMake([tempView center].x-125,[tempView center].y-200 ,200, 200);
    CGImageRef cropped = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageView.image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *img =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped]; //[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped scale:imageView.image.scale orientation:imageView.image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cropped);